# jquery plugin default option modification once applied

Tags: jquery

Take the following example plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.alertOnClick = function(text) {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).click(alert(text));
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

that I might use like this:

```
$('p').alertOnClick("this is a silly plugin");
```

How do I modify the plugin code to support doing the following:

```
$('p').alertOnClick("this is a silly plugin");
$('p#someSpecificP').setAlertText("different alert text");
```

this would have the effect that all `p`'s when clicked should display `"this is a silly plugin"` *except* the `p` with id `"someSpecificP"` which would display `"different alert text"`.

This example is obviously not my real code, but serves as an analogy. I have a plugin applied to many elements with defaults. During the life of the page, I may want to change some of the default settings for individual elements with the plugin applied to them, but not all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it with `data()`, not sure if thats the best approach though...

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.alertOnClick = function(text) {
        return this.each(function(){
                $(this).data('alertText', text).click(function(){
                    alert($(this).data('alertText'));
                });
        });
    }
    $.fn.setAlertText = function(text) {
        return this.data('alertText', text);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
$("p").not("#p1").alertOnClick("Hello");
$("#p1").alertOnClick("Bye");
```

Calling alertOnClick again on an element works. Just remember to unbind all click events and then apply the new one.

Comment: i dont know what `#p1` is when i first assign "hello", so i can't exclude it there with `not`. Therefore calling the same function again will just attach the event listeners twice :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>test 1</p>
<p>test 2</p>
<p id="s1">test 3</p>
<p>test 4</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $.fn.alertOnClick = function(text) {
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).unbind('click');
            $(this).bind('click', {'t' : text}, function(e){
                alert(e.data.t);
            });
        });
   }
})(jQuery);

$('p').alertOnClick('common alert');
$('p#s1').alertOnClick('unique alert');

</script>
```

This works fine for me. I've just unbind previuosly binded events from target elements.

Comment: i'd prefer a solution that doesn't interfere with other code (i.e. your code removes all click event listeners from my element, regardless of whether they had anything to do with alertOnClick or not)

Comment: Oke then. 

Maybe solution is to store all marked elements in some array and it's parameters (alert strings). Every function call will extend existing array and it's parameters...

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it out, but you should be able to define a member function, something like that:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.alertOnClick = function(text) {
        setAlertText: function(newText) {
                $(this).click(alert(newText));
        }

        return this.each(function(){
                $(this).click(alert(text));
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this will make it alert with both messages